# What is the purpose of the limit of a single addressee on comments?

Tags: support, comments

I can see no reason why there is a limit of just one `@addressee` on comments. What problem does this solve?

There has been only a handful of cases where I wanted to address a comment to multiple recipients, but it has always seemed to be an artificial limit.

Comment: Probably to reduce the likelihood this site is perceived as a social network. If you need more then 1 addressee, find yourself a chatroom, those are better equipped to cater discussion.

Comment: I think "what problem is *there*" would be a valid premise.

Comment: @Félix: I don't understand you. One doesn't implement a constraint purely because flouting it would be unnecessary.

Comment: @rene: Thank you for your speculation, but I can think of very much better ways to achieve that purpose. In truth, it seems to be an arbitrary limit without purpose. Maybe those who know will reappear after the weekend.

Comment: @Borodin I basically meant what you added in your edit afterwards, a reason, or case, of why this is seen as a limit.

Comment: In part ... to prevent ping-spamming

Comment: This seems less like a limitation they deliberately added and more like a feature they didn't bother including.

Comment: @BSMP: I assumed the opposite, but perhaps you're right. I guess that providing only one slot for an addressee is really easy to code.

Comment: I guess I need to wait until I come across a situation again where I want to talk to multiple people so that I can talk intelligently about why that is. I would completely agree that adding more than a couple of names is superfluous, especially given that the OP is always included anyway. It would help to know the algorithm for implicit copies, which includes contributors to the discussion anyway, but that is another question.

Answer (score 11):

If you need to break this limitation, then you're using comments *wrong*. Remember: comments are not for having a deep, personal discussion. This is why they're limited to 600 characters. This is why their formatting options are so limited. And so forth.

The same goes here. The more people involved in a comment thread, the greater the chance that they shouldn't be commenting, that they should be getting a chatroom or something to work things out.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Nicol Bolas has already said, another reason why comments are limited to one person is because the owner of the post is already notified as to the posting of a comment. So if you want to get the attention of both the OP and another commenter, then all you need to do is ping the other commenter, and they'll get it.

If you find yourself trying to communicate something to other people, especially more than one and they aren't the OP, then you are no longer commenting on the original post, you are chatting about something else, in which case you should find a forum or somewhere else to talk. Preventing people from pinging multiple people at the same time should have the effect that the person trying to ping several people realizes that they're using comments wrong. Comments should basically be to request clarification, suggest improvements, or add information that others who see the post should consider. If that's what you're doing when you comment, you will never have a need to ping more than one person at a time outside of the OP.

Comment: I've had to delete answers on Meta to stop getting notifications about conversations that had nothing to do with me. There doesn't seem to be a good way to avoid that here but it definitely shouldn't happen on main.

Comment: *"If you find yourself trying to communicate something to other people, especially more than one and they aren't the OP, then you are no longer commenting on the original post, you are chatting about something else"* This is a strange claim: the addressee has nothing to do with the content of the message, and a claim that a comment must be off-topic if it is addressed to more than one person is bizarre.

Comment: @Borodin Why would you ever address something to someone if the content of the message doesn't pertain to him or her? It would be like me pinging BSMP in this comment -- it just wouldn't make sense. Could you elaborate as to why you would ping an addressee then make a comment whose content has nothing to do with that person?

Comment: @Davy: That's not implied by what I wrote. You are saying that it's *impossible* for the content of a single comment to be pertinent to more than one person, which is clearly nonsense.